# как добавить статический метод классу в JS?

Tags: javascript, классы, методы

как добавить статический метод классу в JS?
Так же само как и создание метода в обьекте?

```js
class Karabas {
  constructor() {
  }
}

Karabas.pluss = function (v1, v2) {
  console.log(String(v1) + v2)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что, собственно, не работает в Вашем коде?

```js
class Karabas {
  constructor() {
  }
}

Karabas.pluss = function (v1, v2) {
  console.log(String(v1) + v2)
}

Karabas.pluss(1, 2);
```

Пример (`Animal.eat = function() { ... }`) здесь:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: да, работает) вызывал метод на обьекте)